# how to access windows partitions from linux terminal?

Tags: partitioning

how to access windows partitions like C or D from Linux terminal
using commands
because I want to work on some `.cpp` files there using "GCC" compiler
as I don't want to change their directory to e.g. Linux desktop

I used `cd /dev/sda2` but nothing happened.
please help

Answer (score 11):

They are normally mounted on `/media/USERNAME/MountName`

For example, I have a windows drive which has the label "xtreme". This partition is mounted on `/media/cyrex/xtreme` where **cyrex** is my username.

If you are in the Unity Desktop you should see something like in the Unity launcher:

[image]

It looks like a hard drive, if you click on it, it will automatically mount the partition on `/media/USERNAME`. In my case, as I mentioned above, when I clicked on it, it mounted on the folder `/media/USERNAME/xtreme` (As mentioned before).

Now, if you want to mount that **sda2** somewhere else, for example in `/mnt`, you can simply type in the terminal:

`mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`

Note that the 2 in **sda2** means it is the second partition on that drive, which might mean it is the **D:** in your windows system (It depends on the other the hard drive was partitioned in the first place).

So if you have a **C:** and **D:** drives, assuming both are **sda1** and **sda2** and you want to mount them in `/media/rami/` then you would:

1. Create a folder for each (So you know which one is which)

   `mkdir /media/rami/cdrive`
   `mkdir /media/rami/ddrive`
2. Mount each one to the already created folders

   `mount /dev/sda1/ /media/rami/cdrive`
   `mount /dev/sda2/ /media/rami/ddrive`

note that there are many other ways of doing it, like setting the partitions to mount automatically via `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the partition that Windows is using is sda2.

Create a folder for mounting

```
mkdir /folder_name
```

Mount the partition

```
mount /sda2 /folder_name
```

To unmount the partition 
`umount /folder_name` or `umount /sda2 /folder_name`

Answer (score 0):

first type: **cd /**

now you will see your root directories but before you were in home

then :**ls**

type: **cd media**

type:**cd root**

type: **ls**

now you will see your windows partitions so you can go inside any one of them 
by cd

type:**cd**

Comment: Why not `cd /media/root/[windows partition] && ls`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in dual boot windows 10 and Deepin 15.11.
Made an additional 20Gb partition on the hard disk and formatted this in FAT32. Now I can read / write from linux and windows, without going through a pendrive or other usb hard disk, for saving.

Comment: In effect, i have in dual boot C drive 120GB, D drive 80GB (ntfs), then a 20Gb partition (FAT32), then linux root, swap and /home partitions. in Deepin, I can access save files created in linux to this partition, and read write from windows or deepin